# Handling Localization with Alexa Skill

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I've recently written a simple skill on for the Alexa, and would be interested to see if anyone has added any localization to their skills to get them working across languages, especially now they are bringing more locations (India/Japan etc) on board.

It would be good to use the same code base but just respond in different languages based on where the user is. The best way i can see so far it to request the users postcode/country and then use that to setup the response

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html) to the Amazon doc on how to support multiple languages.